# cURL example for accessing authenticated Kraken API

Tags: bash, curl, openssl, api, base64

I've been trying to implement a client for Kraken private API (https://www.kraken.com/help/api) and because I've been running into some issues with that, I've been trying to access that same API with cURL.

However, I can't get for the life of me get it to work and I think I may not be using the right command line tools to generate the hashes and digests.

When accessing the private API the following headers need to be added to the request:

```
API-Key = «key»
API-Sign = Message signature using HMAC-SHA512 of (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded «secret»
```

On the command line I do the following steps:

- `echo -n "123nonce=123" | openssl sha256`

result: `(stdin)= 353f9df92ab1d5e5afe06bb7d1bb42a8ef6654b633d94818007aeafbaf03ca3d`

- `echo -n "/0/private/Balance353f9df92ab1d5e5afe06bb7d1bb42a8ef6654b633d94818007aeafbaf03ca3d" | openssl sha512 -hmac $(echo -n "wqtzZWNyZXTCuw==" | base64 -d)`

result: `(stdin)= 6f19f8f058b0e6dc835692840ccdebc1c415f00d42b75b3d3c21ef5fd43f006e30cc9b51c63aba3268a534bf68978d60d2362bffd31c8125553fb8ec41b2f64d`

- `echo -n "6f19f8f058b0e6dc835692840ccdebc1c415f00d42b75b3d3c21ef5fd43f006e30cc9b51c63aba3268a534bf68978d60d2362bffd31c8125553fb8ec41b2f64d" | base64`

result:

```
NmYxOWY4ZjA1OGIwZTZkYzgzNTY5Mjg0MGNjZGViYzFjNDE1ZjAwZDQyYjc1YjNkM2MyMWVmNWZk
NDNmMDA2ZTMwY2M5YjUxYzYzYWJhMzI2OGE1MzRiZjY4OTc4ZDYwZDIzNjJiZmZkMzFjODEyNTU1
M2ZiOGVjNDFiMmY2NGQ=
```

- `curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "API-Key: «key»" -H "API-Sign: NmYxOWY4ZjA1OGIwZTZkYzgzNTY5Mjg0MGNjZGViYzFjNDE1ZjAwZDQyYjc1YjNkM2MyMWVmNWZkNDNmMDA2ZTMwY2M5YjUxYzYzYWJhMzI2OGE1MzRiZjY4OTc4ZDYwZDIzNjJiZmZkMzFjODEyNTU1M2ZiOGVjNDFiMmY2NGQ=" -d "nonce=123" https://api.kraken.com/0/private/Balance`

result (assuming valid «key» and «secret»): `{"error":["EAPI:Invalid signature"]}`

But no matter which permutations I try I keep getting the "Invalid signature" error.

These permutations include but are not limited to:

- Base64 encoding the API-Sign value (*all* publicly available Kraken clients do this),
- uppercasing whatever is to be Base64 encoded,
- leaving out the '/' in front of the URI path,
- leaving out the actual nonce number at the front of the SHA256.

Comment: you could try to use one of the working api implementations listed, like the python2 one, and add some debug to see where the difference is.

Comment: Thanks meuh, that made the problem immediately obvious. Kinda silly that I didn't try that before posting my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to meuh I figured out the issue. Since I can imagine other people being as silly as me I'll answer my own question:

The problem is that I'm using strings instead of bytes.  I don't have the time to figure it out for the command line and cURL (perhaps someone else wants to do that and I'll accept that answer).

For the client I was working on, instead of concatenating `/0/private/Balance` and the SHA256 hex string `353f9df92ab1d5e5afe06bb7d1bb42a8ef6654b633d94818007aeafbaf03ca3d` I should concatenate the bytes for "/0/private/Balance" (`47 48 47 112 114 105 118 97 116 101 47 66 97 108 97 110 99 101`) and SHA256("123nonce=123") (`53 63 157 249 42 177 213 229 175 224 107 183 209 187 66 168 239 102 84 182 51 217 72 24 0 122 234 251 175 3 202 61`) (shown as decimal values this time).

Same for the SHA512 HMAC.

**Edit:**

Since someone asked on Twitter, these are the actual steps to do it on the commandline:

1. `echo -n "/0/private/Balance" > tmp.bin`
2. `echo -n "123nonce=123" | openssl sha256 -binary >> tmp.bin`
3. `cat tmp.bin | openssl sha512 -binary -hmac $(echo -n "wqtzZWNyZXTCuw==" | base64 -d) | base64` ("wqtzZWNyZXTCuw==" is "«secret»" BASE64 encoded, this should ofcourse be *your* secret)
4. `curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "API-Key: «key»" -H "API-Sign: «output-from-step-3»" -d "nonce=123" https://api.kraken.com/0/private/Balance`

As you can seen above, the one thing that was forgotten in the original question was using the `-binary` switch.

**Note: your API key and secret will end up on the commandline (visible with `ps aux`) and in your shell history!**

Comment: This solution is perfect, but I needed to add a `-w 0` after the second `base64` to avoid splitting the output in two (without `-w`, the output is formated in two columns of 76 characters). You also forgot a `$` sign before the parenthesis. Final command for line 3: `cat tmp.bin | openssl sha512 -binary -hmac $(echo -n "wqtzZWNyZXTCuw==" | base64 -d) | base64 -w 0`

Comment: The forgotten `$` sign is because I use the fish shell. I should have assumed Bourne shell, sorry.